# Reverse a read only tuple

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples, array-reverse

How I can reverse this array of "readonly" function tuples? I borrowed Reverse from this library here [typescript- tuple](https://github.com/ksxnodemodules/typescript-tuple/blob/master/lib/utils.ts#L272-L285).

> [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=33#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVALgSwDZSQbwFgAoJUpCADxgHsAnNJNATxmQEkoAxDYDNCADwAVAK4wsySv2AATXCGBMA2gF0ANEm69%20GtsABmPPhAB8SALz5iZG%20TAxmALk1H%20126WDVgAUXtOkAApAgDowgH1nUXEIAEoLMwUmeKkIWVxgyKQefQhaF1ooNA0wkPCARmccvKQAJWg0ePNExVj3DwB%20JA4tYwF6oo1enW6DV1N222dgCAA3PMmbHPHnPUNtCEmAXyVFsmiJcgppOSRVJC6Acgh-JkukRz3SA8ljtNPA6vyfCUhgRvOHSeSB%20NzSaHOqXSSBeF2Bl2WG0uwOcly8vluyJIHgeSBm81okxUxEmlBo9EYLGQAAVaBBWLJhGJDlDTklVBoAIIyGTvMzmYGZZzc3myEoRSow5lxBJIJIpN7Q4KlLJfOrQERYRqy%20UXdVQTUMaZzBZEEnY0hkugMZisdUEqCCWGs%20SKDlIWkQQwUI4nV3KFQWM4qflWC22G4OJjOT3etTA9F%20KPOZURKLSpotZK%2094ZQKqgw1biFYpIFWStUAOSkmblrWBXXqDsE1eOGk9DJkAljGAoQwwJZMJhReJNhPDSzGG2chAnOJ8tVqAHlaqiAMIKLwMOnNuvZKfGRjSrE42xrpcAER8lc5AFkfKi1uMXiecVttrs589pTnoUokuKITsioxJfnqPTjEyMQaGi3hJswlwwYixiXMOYGopGCFEsQ75mkQAD0%20FIAAFmgaAwFAjiEQA5nwxEiAARiE8DUGA%20EANZQBQXi8mA1AyJq0D4ba0DwLQGAOAAtGg0r4RgUAGkJ5QAOzmlaFIieqIAyJwIjAPAuCWHS2neFgTBBIEFDOLqzR1skqjEOpNpUvaeSOlBLKKmybohkG6DYFAIRNm5TrSmhxAscARRHOAMRBkogS1pckDUAA7pcgYgLgkVFOammzEGwWFIIInUPoMX2BIJhAA)

```
namespace Utils {
    export type IsFinite<Tuple extends any[], Finite, Infinite> = {
        empty: Finite
        nonEmpty: ((..._: Tuple) => any) extends ((_: infer First, ..._1: infer Rest) => any)
        ? IsFinite<Rest, Finite, Infinite>
        : never
        infinite: Infinite
    }[
        Tuple extends [] ? 'empty' :
        Tuple extends (infer Element)[] ?
        Element[] extends Tuple ?
        'infinite'
        : 'nonEmpty'
        : never
    ]

    export type Prepend<Tuple extends any[], Addend> =
        ((_: Addend, ..._1: Tuple) => any) extends ((..._: infer Result) => any) ? Result : never


    export type Reverse<Tuple extends any[], Prefix extends any[] = []> = {
        empty: Prefix,
        nonEmpty: ((..._: Tuple) => any) extends ((_: infer First, ..._1: infer Next) => any)
        ? Reverse<Next, Prepend<Prefix, First>>
        : never
        infinite: {
            ERROR: 'Cannot reverse an infinite tuple'
            CODENAME: 'InfiniteTuple'
        }
    }[
        Tuple extends [any, ...any[]]
        ? IsFinite<Tuple, 'nonEmpty', 'infinite'>
        : 'empty'
    ]
}
```

```
export type ReadFuncs = readonly ((x: any) => any)[]
export type Reverse<Tuple extends any[]> = Utils.Reverse<Tuple>

const example = [() => 'meow'] as const

type v = Reverse<typeof example>
```

> [Playground with Readonly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=33#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVALgSwDZSQbwFgAoJUpCADxgHsAnNJNATxmQEkoAxDYDNCADwAVAK4wsySv2AATXLQggZ1YFiZIQwJgG0AugBok3Xv0NtgAMx58IAPiQBefMTKvyYGMwBcR6-xdupMAqAKIe3kgAFJEAdHEA%20j6i4hAAlI72mkzpUhCyuNGJSDwWELS%20tFBohnEx8QCMPiVlSABK0GjpDplaqQGBAPxIHMY2Au1VhqOmw5Z%20dv1uPsAQAG5li64l8z7mViYQiwC%202ptkyRLkFNJySHpIQwDkEOFMj0heZ6QXktd5t5FmuUQhJIMBOvcBl8kCCXnk0PdcvkkD8HtDHtsDo9oT5HsFgGFPG8cUgVutaItdMRFpQaPRGCxkAAFBSsWTCMSXJG3BRKFRqDRaPSGACCMhk-3sDmhhR8YolshqCUaKM5aQyguyVxuBViCSalhaExEWE6Gqy6SGxtNH1Jaw2RGpJDItLoDGYrDa9sqglR3PkimUqnUWWFSBZECsFG1-wDfODmvuTj0UuczsCLyJPgjUf00PxhIi0VqRR%20XR6Wv9UUiRSBFUmSBLKrrADkpOXNX1024rd6oII29dDBG2TIBDmMBQphhKmhbLYSWSHYFSJibD5CN2VzDWq0APKtXEAYU0wQYCnJ-cFxTmB0YauxW5XR73ABEQi2RQBZEK4vbzH5H23I5jlOJ9vjVGNkW0LIlRiXkgwFUNdCpcCHmGLh5g5FJDDxUJXkeXC134R4FzQ3FM2YICyFQkDHSIAB6BikAACzQNAYCgLwmIAcz4FiRAAIxieBqDABiAGsoAoYIJTAagZBNaAGI9aB4FoDBPAAWjQNUGIwKAoBEZT6gAdidV16VUr0lE4ERgHgXAnAQ-l1GiCgfAtc1ej0YhLPdRkvUvX1IKrdpbPsxzU3QbAoBidpguwiQyOIUTgCqK5wBSRw7kiDtHkgagAHdCKiDsAGZdA0XA0qqJ1rNWHKErKfsBFU6gLEyjxkqAA)

Comment: Have you tried inserting `readonly` before every tuple or array type mentioned in the code?

Comment: @jcalz Yes I have, `Reverse` comes back empty, added playground example above.

Comment: I still see things like `Tuple extends []` instead of `Tuple extends readonly []`, etc.